# WPF binding custom list of grids width to a single resizable grid, really laggy with 100s of grids

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

So I'm working on a program that list game servers. Once I have my List containing all the servers, I programmatically create a StackPanel (Horizontal) and 4 grids, 1 for each column, and fill in the server info (For each of the servers). Then I add that StackPanel to another StackPanel in my XAML. Above this list I have the headers created with a grid and some column definitions. Each of the servers columns widths are bound to the width of these header column widths. It works fine, but resizing the columns becomes really slow with > 500 items, and my list usually contains ~1500 servers. Here's my code:

WPF

```
<Grid x:Name="Content_Servers">
    <Grid Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=Content_Servers, Path=ActualWidth}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="500" MinWidth="400"></ColumnDefinition>
            <!-- Server Name -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" MinWidth="150"></ColumnDefinition>
            <!-- Map -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" MinWidth="80"></ColumnDefinition>
            <!-- Players -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70" MinWidth="70"></ColumnDefinition>
            <!-- Ping -->
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Column_Name" SizeChanged="Column_Name_SizeChanged">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="17" Margin="15, 0, 0, 0"><Run Text="Name"></Run></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" ResizeDirection="Columns" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="2" Background="White" Opacity=".4"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="2" x:Name="Column_Map">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="17" Margin="15, 0, 0, 0"><Run Text="Map"></Run></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" ResizeDirection="Columns" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="2" Background="White" Opacity=".4"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="4" x:Name="Column_Players">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="17" Margin="15, 0, 0, 0"><Run Text="Players"></Run></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="5" ResizeDirection="Columns" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="2" Background="White" Opacity=".4"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="6" x:Name="Column_Ping">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="17" Margin="15, 0, 0, 0"><Run Text="Ping"></Run></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0, 30, 0, 25">
        <StackPanel x:Name="ServerStackPanel" Orientation="Vertical">
            <!-- Servers get added here -->
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
private void AddServerItem(ServerInfo ServerDetails)
{
    // Grid contains the entire item
    Grid ServerContainer = new Grid();

    // Stack panel for each of the columns
    StackPanel ColumnStack = new StackPanel();
    ColumnStack.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

    // 3 more block like this, to contain the elements in each column:
    Grid ColumnName = new Grid();
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    ColumnName.Margin = new Thickness(3, 0, 0, 0);
    Binding BindName = new Binding();
    BindName.ElementName = "Column_Name";
    BindName.Path = new PropertyPath(Grid.ActualWidthProperty);
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(ColumnName, Grid.WidthProperty, BindName);

    // Element for the first column, every other column is more or less the same
    TextBlock ServerNameTB = new TextBlock();
    ServerNameTB.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    ServerNameTB.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    ServerNameTB.Foreground = Brushes.White;
    ServerNameTB.FontSize = 18;
    ServerNameTB.Margin = new Thickness(15, 2, 0, 0);
    ServerNameTB.Text = ServerDetails.Name;

    // Add all the children
    ColumnName.Children.Add(ServerNameTB);
    ColumnStack.Children.Add(ColumnName);
    ServerContainer.Children.Add(ColumnStack);
    ServerStackPanel.Children.Add(ServerContainer);
}
```

One thing I noticed is the columns with only a few chars in the TextBlock (like the ping column) resized normally, where the server name column lags considerably and contains >50 chars

I like the approach I take because it gives me a lot of customization if I want to change anything, the single problem of course being the lag when resizing columns when the list has 100s of items. Is there any way I can keep this approach but reduce/remove the lag? My knowledge of WPF and C# is mediocre, so any help is appreciated.

I do of course know about datagrids, but I like my way and I'm stubborn. But if I cant find a solution I guess I'll have to use them.

Comment: Refreshing usually slows controls down.  So you may be able to speed up operation by turning off refresh except visible StackPanels.

Comment: Why are you nesting so much `Grids` for a simple `TextBlock`?

Comment: @lokusking , I want to be able to add more controls and functionality for each server item so there will be more than just a TextBlock in each grid, and I prefer how much layout customization I can do.